# basic twitter search using python Tweepy library, doesn't work

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Python 3.10, Tweepy version 4.10.0, trying to make basic search through tweets.

```
import tweepy     
consumer_key_str = 'Some consumer key'
consumer_secret_str = 'some consumer secret'
bearer_token_str = 'some bearer token string'

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token_str)
client.consumer_key = api_key_str
client.consumer_secret = consumer_secret_str
```

I am trying to search it using something like:

```
res = client.search_all_tweets(query='query=sunshine')
```

but, I am getting an error:

```
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.
```

I am unfamiliar with it all. I have created all the keys, and have a 'project' on a twitter developer portal.
Note that when I am trying to acquire some tweets using:

```
tweet_ids = [1460323737035677698, 1293593516040269825, 1293595870563381249]
response = client.get_tweets(tweet_ids , tweet_fields=["created_at", "text", "geo"])
```

it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

The `search_all_tweets` method is accessible only if you have an Academic access.

You can read more about the access levels in the [Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-level).